# Why myObject.function() throwing 'is not a function' error? (trying to learn functional instantiation)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to create a class using a function and giving it some props and a method. If I do the same thing in C# in class-based way and call the mothod this will work fine but in JS it gives me an error. My question is why it behaves in a different way.

code snippet:

```
function Animal (name) {
    let animal = {}
    animal.name = name;
    animal.eat = function (){ 
        console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
    }
}

let myAnimal = new Animal('dog');
console.log(myAnimal.eat()); //Uncaught TypeError: myAnimal.eat is not a function at proto.js:11
```

Comment: the variable `animal` is only "accessible" within the `function Animal` - did you mean to use `this` instead?

Comment: You missed a statement `return animal;` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if `Animal` is going to act as a constructor of your *sort of class*, then you would need to write it like a proper constructor, i.e. drop the `let animal = {}` bit, and just set properties on `this`:

```js
function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.eat = function (){ 
        console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
    }
}

let myAnimal = new Animal('dog');
myAnimal.eat();
```

now this approach has the downside of creating a new function `eat()` for each instance of `Animal` instead of binding an existing function `eat()` to each instance, which is what happens normally with classes. that you can achieve by this:

```js
function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function (){ 
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
}

let myAnimal = new Animal('dog');
myAnimal.eat();
```

which is actually the proper way people used to define classes in javascript before `class` was introduced.

however, you can also drop the whole *class-like* concept, and just have an `Animal()` function that gives out an object with desired properties:

```js
function Animal (name) {
    let animal = {};
    animal.name = name;
    animal.eat = function (){ 
        console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
    }
    
    return animal;
}

let myAnimal = Animal('dog');
myAnimal.eat();
```

note how in this approach you have `let myAnimal = Animal('dog')` instead of `let myAnimal = new Animal('dog')`, as `Animal()` is no longer a constructor.

*reminder*: this is an explanation of how you can instantiate objects with a function, and by no means the recommended way of defining classes in javascript. in older environments, the `prototype` approach is the recommended way, for newer environments, just use `class`.

Answer (score 3):

This would be the prototypical way to achieve that in JavaScript:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
}

new Animal('Pooch').eat();
```

Or with the introduction of [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (since ECMAScript 2015):

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  eat() {
    console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
  }
}

new Animal('Pooch').eat();
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with Robby's approach above. For correcting your code, you missed a statement `return animal;` :)

```js
function Animal (name) {
      let animal = {}
      animal.name = name;
      animal.eat = function (){ 
        console.log(`${this.name} is eating`)
       }
      return animal;
     }

    let myAnimal = new Animal('dog');
    console.log(myAnimal.eat());
```

Comment: This approach has the downside that the function is re-created for every instance though...

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen, I'll keep that in mind when come across classes again!